# Breadcrumbs in not updating according to current route in react-router-dom version 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, breadcrumbs

When I am getting this page below,  the breadcrumb is not binding according to this page.
How to implement current route to breadcrumbs each time  ?

[image]

Comment: Please, share the implementation of the breadcrumbs. Screenshot does not help.

Comment: I used material ui <Breadcrumbs> element with hard code now. but I want dynamic according to routes

Comment: There's an example how to use that component with `react-router` right in their documentation https://material-ui.com/components/breadcrumbs/#integration-with-react-router . If that's not enough, you will probably have to share the code so somebody could look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this article link. It will cover your single and nested routes using latest react-router-dom v6.

[Breadcrumbs with react-router-dom version 6](https://medium.com/@code.kamran/how-to-update-material-ui-breadcrumbs-from-react-router-v6-e4ec033ceab8)

Comment: Resolved. I have tried and it's working for nested routes.